# Is it ok to upvote questions

Tags: discussion, questions, voting

Should I upvote a question if I answer it?

Does the fact that I am answering make a question a good question?

If a question produces good answers, does that make it a good question?

I'm confused.

Comment: The question Title should have " that I've answered" added to it.

Comment: @RayButterworth I am concerned about questions when someone else answers too.

Comment: @RayButterworth Like this question. https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/123129/95237

Comment: @RayButterworth Zero votes means it isn’t a good question.

Comment: Related meta-pse question: [If a question is worth answering, it's probably worth upvoting](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5596/if-a-question-is-worth-answering-its-probably-worth-upvoting)

Comment: @scottbb The responses seem a bit toxic. I hope it’s not representative.

Comment: @BobMacaroniMcStevens which responses? There are only 3.

Comment: @BobMacaroniMcStevens, my suggestion was because, as it is currently written, the Title is far more general than what you are actually asking.

Comment: @RayButterworth My third paragraph generalizes.

Comment: @BobMacaroniMcStevens, it's generally best to ask exactly one question per question. Asking four questions in one confuses us readers.

Comment: @RayButterworth I asked one question. Its in the title.

Comment: @BobMacaroniMcStevens, if the Title is your only question, the answer is "*Obviously it's okay, otherwise Stack Exchange wouldn't provide a mechanism for doing it.*" (e.g try up-voting your own question, and you'll find that it won't let you.).  And if that is your "one question", the other questions don't belong in the body of the answer; they only confuse the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Without wanting to be *too* unhelpful, you should upvote questions you think are good questions. *One* way to determine this is by the tooltip on the upvote button:

> This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear

It is perfectly possible for you to think a question is not a good question ("This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful") but still one you can write a good answer to - although often these questions are duplicates of previously asked questions, so do look for that first.

A question that produces good answers is an indication that it is a good question, but I wouldn't say always a good question. At times, there can be questions which are incredibly lazily written, but a community member puts an heroic amount of effort into writing a superb answer. In those cases, it's often possible to improve the question by editing it!

Comment: How does a person know how much effort someone else made?

Comment: I've always found "*shows research effort; it is useful and clear*" to be ambiguous: does the ";" mean, "or" or "and"?  I'm not looking for an answer to that, or reasons why it means what it does; I'm pointing out that the fact I can ask that question means that the statement itself is poorly worded.

Comment: Why be unhelpful at all?